# Solve integral $\int \int \int_A \frac{dxdydz}{(x+y+1)^2}$ where $A=\{(x,y,z):0<x<1, 0<x+y<1, 0<z(x+y+1)<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I need to solve following integral
$$
\int \int \int_A \frac{dxdydz}{(x+y+1)^2}
$$
where $A=\{(x,y,z):0<x<1, 0<x+y<1, 0<z(x+y+1)<1\}$

If I do not take $z$ into consideration, I know how to solve it. I should use Fubini theorem here. Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could interchange the order?

$$\int\int\int_A\frac{dxdydz}{(x+y+1)^2}$$
$$=\ \int_0^1\int_{-x}^{1-x}\int_0^{\frac1{x+y+1}}\frac1{(x+y+1)^2}\ dzdydx$$
$$=\ \int_0^1\int_{-x}^{1-x}\frac1{(x+y+1)^3}\ dydx$$
$$=\ \int_0^1\left.\frac1{-2(x+y+1)^2}\right|_{y=-x}^{y=1-x}\,dx$$
$$=\ \int_0^1\frac38\ dx$$
$$=\frac38$$

Sorry if I make a mistake here, I have not been dealing with integral for quite a long time

Comment: After the second step (integration by $dz$) the result should have $(x+y+1)^3$ in denominator, not $(x+y+1)$

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak Thanks a lot, I indeed made a mistake...

Comment: Substituting $1-x$ and $-x$ in should give $\frac{3}{8}$ not $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @B.Mehta Thanks, I really should stop answering questions today...